# Django channels with postgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, django-channels

I'm working on a project and I need to use Django-channels in it.

I followed [this tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html) step by step but it used Redis to make layer (which is not supported in Windows OS) so is it possible to use PostgreSQL instead of Redis for stack data?

sorry for my bad grammar! English is not my native language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with **Postgresql**.
I would rather suggest you to install **[Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)** and then running a `redis` instance. You would run a command similar to this after installing `docker` properly.

```sh
docker run -p 6379:6379 redis:latest
```

This will run a `redis` instance inside docker which you will be able to access through the **6379** port.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use PostgreSQL with [channels_postgres](https://github.com/danidee10/channels_postgres)

It's a drop-in replacement for the official Redis backend

PS: I'm the author :-)